# Need help with xorg.conf for dual Radeon HD6450 video cards with 4 monitors

Tags: ati, xorg, multiple-monitors, radeon

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity and have dual (2) Radeon HD6450 video cards and 4 Hanns-G HL273 monitors. Each Radeon card is driving one monitor via DVI and the other via VGA. I am running the proprietary video drivers from AMD's web site: "amd-catalyst-13.11-beta V9.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run"  I tried to use "amd-catalyst-13.12-linux-x86.x86_64.run" but could not get that newer version to install.

What I need help with is how to "correct" my xorg.conf file and any other needed instructions to get all four of my monitors to work as a continuous desktop that allows me to drag things from one monitor to the next, etc.

When I tried to use the default open source drivers that came in Ubuntu 13.10, only three of the monitors would work. Now that I am running the proprietary ones, all four monitors come on and I can move my mouse from one end to the other--but only the right-most monitor displays my desktop and allows me to "do anything". Any time I move my mouse to any of the other three monitors (which display all-white), it turns into an "X" and does not do anything else but move. Enabling xinerama makes all four displays go all-black after login.

I do have amdcccle installed, but it does not seem to have the ability to handle my particular configuration.

My Current xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "Basic Layout"
Screen 0 "Screen1" 5760 0
Screen 1 "Screen0" 0 0
Screen 2 "Screen2" 3840 0
Screen 3 "Screen3" 1920 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "0-DFP2"
Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
Option "DPMS" "true"
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
Option "TargetRefresh" "60"
Option "Position" "0 0"
Option "Rotate" "normal"
Option "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "0-CRT1"
Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
Option "DPMS" "true"
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
Option "TargetRefresh" "60"
Option "Position" "0 0"
Option "Rotate" "normal"
Option "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "1-DFP2"
Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
Option "DPMS" "true"
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
Option "TargetRefresh" "60"
Option "Position" "0 0"
Option "Rotate" "normal"
Option "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "1-CRT1"
Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
Option "DPMS" "true"
Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
Option "TargetRefresh" "60"
Option "Position" "0 0"
Option "Rotate" "normal"
Option "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device0"
Driver "fglrx"
Option "Monitor-CRT1" "1-CRT1"
BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device1"
Driver "fglrx"
Option "Monitor-DFP2" "0-DFP2"
BusID "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device2"
Driver "fglrx"
Option "Monitor-DFP2" "1-DFP2"
BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "Device3"
Driver "fglrx"
Option "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
BusID "PCI:4:0:0"
Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device "Device0"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen1"
Device "Device1"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen2"
Device "Device2"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Viewport 0 0
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen3"
Device "Device3"
DefaultDepth 24
SubSection "Display"
Viewport 0 0
Depth 24
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: If it's a dualboot: does it work on Windows? Also: are the 2 vga monitors on the same video card or on different cards?

Comment: It is not a dual boot machine.  I generally use CentOS, but I have decided to give Ubuntu a serious try.  Each video card has: 1 DVI, 1 HDMI, and 1 VGA connection.  We use many of these cards for dual monitor set-ups, though this is the only machine where we have installed two of the cards in the same machine.  Both cards worked as dual-screen when in other machines, so I think it is safe to assume that the cards both work.

Comment: Since I wrote this, I have moved to the proprietary drivers from AMD--but still with no joy.  <sigh>

Comment: Have you only tried it with unity or also with gnome? I guess it would have to do with the DM, since it does work on CentOS (they are the same drivers I expect) Oh and, It would be best if you included the information you gave in your response in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... Actually, I have fully edited the original question for both clarity and to update according to what I have done/learned in the meantime.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

So after exhaustive trial and error, research, etc., I finally determined that both Gnome3 and Unity require composite mode to operate--but Xinerama does not support that mode.  I will be switching my desktop to XFCE--which has complete support for Xinerama and thus will handle all four of my monitors.

There's a lot of chatter about how Xinerama is deprecated, etc.  Well, that's fine--but what's the alternative?  Some folks talk about using xrandr instead, but I do not see how that will achieve the desired result.

So... at least at this point, my answer is to ditch Unity in favor of XFCE--and here is how I did it:

Install the new XFCE desktop...

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop gksu leafpad synaptic
```

When the process is complete, log out of the session, but do NOT shutdown.

When the login box appears, click on the Ubuntu logo next to your user name and select "Xubuntu Session", then log in with your normal password.

Now to clean up and remove un-needed Unity pieces and parts:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus gnome-power-manager compiz compiz-gnome unity unity-* unity8* hud zeitgeist zeitgeist-core python-zeitgeist libzeitgeist* activity-log-manager-common gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot
```

Reboot.

Install/reinstall ATI binary drivers and use command:

```
aticonfig --adapter=all --xinerama --initial
```

Comment: That last codeblock is wrong, use this one instead: `aticonfig --adapter=all --xinerama on --initial`